# Don't apply ActionFilterAttribute to a specific route?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MvC .Net web application and am applying an action filter attribute to all routes. How do I configure it so that this filter is NOT applied for a specific route (ie "/api/ignore") I specify in WebApiConfig.cs?

In my Globax.asax.cs, I have these 2 lines in Application_Start() so this filter is called.

```
ISessionFilter sessionFilter = (ISessionFilter) DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISessionFilter>();

GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(sessionFilter);
```

This is my filter:

```
public class SessionFilter : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute, System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter, ISessionFilter
{

        public SessionFilter()
        {
        }

        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
        //logic here
        }
}
```

Is there a clean way to do this? Do I need to hard code the route to ignore in my filter class (I'd prefer not to do this)

Comment: Consider making it opt-in (each controller can specify attribute)... Otherwise zagros' (+1) solution shows generic way for individual controllers/actions to opt out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails there's something called :skip_before_filter... Unfortunately, in .NET you need to do something like this (basically make a dummy attribute that when you put on an action, depending on some condition of your liking, stops that action's execution):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class HanlleyDisable : Attribute { }

public class SessionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        bool disabled = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(HanlleyDisable ), true) ||
                        filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(HanlleyDisable), true);
        if (disabled)
            return;    

        // action filter logic here...
    }
}

class FooController  {  

    [HanlleyDisable]
    MyMethod() { ... } 

}
```